# After running android app imported packages are visible on phone

Tags: android, apk

I have created my first Android App which uses a QR code package (com.jwetherell.quick_response_code). The integration works good.
However, when I deploy the application to the phone, not only the app icon is visible but also some android package icons which are useless without the app's functionality.

In what way should I configure the deployment that only the app icon is visible?

[image]

Comment: Check your Android Manifest file. I think that you have more that one activity with <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"> cateogory

Comment: Fantastic, that works. Thank you @KonradKrakowiak, If you provide this as the answer then I will marked is as solved.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I'm glad that I could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Android Manifest file. I think that you have more that one activity with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
```

category.